# Spring localechangeinterceptor not working

Tags: spring, internationalization, locale

I searched many topics but I couldnt find a solution.My internalization works when i set defaultlocale in spring-servlet.xml, but I cannot change locale when i clicked link and set new locale.
English

My xml is below ;

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xmlns:c="http://www.springframework.org/schema/c"
 xmlns:cache="http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache"
 xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
 xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
 xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
 xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache/spring-cache-3.1.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.1.xsd">
 
 <bean id="internalResourceViewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
  p:prefix="/WEB-INF/view/"
  p:suffix=".jsp"  />
 
 
 <bean id="messageSource"
        class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource"
        p:basename="language.messages"
        p:useCodeAsDefaultMessage="true"/>
 
 <mvc:interceptors>
     <mvc:interceptor>
         <mvc:mapping path="/**" />
         <bean id="localeChangeInterceptor"
             class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
             <property name="paramName" value="language" />
         </bean>
     </mvc:interceptor>
 </mvc:interceptors>
 
 <bean id="localeResolver"
     class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.CookieLocaleResolver">
     <property name="cookieName" value="language" />
     <property name="defaultLocale" value="tr" />
 </bean>
   
  
 
 <!-- Configure the multipart resolver -->
    <bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
        <property name="maxUploadSize" value="5097152" />
    </bean>
    
 <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver">      
  <property name="order" value="1" />      
  <property name="mediaTypes">        
   <map>           
     <entry key="json" value="application/json" />           
     <entry key="xml" value="application/xml" />           
     <entry key="pdf" value="application/pdf" /> 
     <entry key="xlsx" value="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet" />        
   </map>      
  </property>       
  
  <property name="defaultViews">        
   <list>          
    <!-- JSON View -->          
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJackson2JsonView" p:prettyPrint="true" >          
    </bean>          
    
    <!--  XML view -->            
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.xml.MarshallingView">            
    <constructor-arg>                
     <bean class="org.springframework.oxm.castor.CastorMarshaller">                   
                
     </bean>            
    </constructor-arg>          
    </bean>          
    
    <!--  PDF view -->          
    <bean class="com.sni.spring.view.PDFView">             
    </bean>
    
    <!--  XLSX "Excel" view -->          
    <bean class="com.sni.spring.view.ExcelView">             
    </bean>
   </list>      
  </property>      
  
  <property name="ignoreAcceptHeader" value="true" />     
 </bean>
 
  
</beans>
```

Comment: Add `<mvc:annotation-driven />` and make sure that this file is loaded by the `DispatcherServlet` NOT the `ContextLoaderListener`.

Comment: Thank you so much, It has worked.You saved by day =)

Comment: Thank you. This saved my day...