# Locale only getting values for default locale while other locale is not displaying

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

hi I am working on spring locale but it is still getting values from one locale not from other here is my code so far
**dispatcherServlet**

```
    <mvc:annotation-driven enable-matrix-variables="true" />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.*" />
    <bean id="messageSource"
            class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
            <property name="basenames">
                <list>
                    <value>/com/resources/messages_en</value>
                    <value>/com/resources/messages_nl</value>
                </list>
            </property>
            <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
        </bean>
        <bean id="localeResolver"
            class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.SessionLocaleResolver">
        </bean>
        <mvc:interceptors>
            <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
                <property name="paramName" value="language" />
            </bean>
        </mvc:interceptors>
```

and this is I am using in my **page.jsp**

```
<%@ taglib uri='http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core' prefix='c'%>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>
        <b><h3>
                <a href="?language=en">English</a>| <a href="?language=nl">Dutch</a>
            </h3></b>
    </p>
    <spring:message code="tagline"></spring:message>
    <hr>
</body>
</html>
```

For English, everything works fine but while clicking on `Dutch` its also showing English too, how to resolve that?

this is only data in my files :

```
1 message_en.properties
tagline=This is English

2 message_nl.properties
tagline=This is dutch
```

Please Help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have `<mvc:annotation-driven />` in you config. Also your `<mvc:interceptors>` should be like below.

```
 <mvc:interceptors>
     <mvc:interceptor>
        <mvc:mapping path="/**" />
          <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
              <property name="paramName" value="language" />
          </bean>
   </mvc:interceptor>
</mvc:interceptors>
```

And MessageSource bean

```
<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
   <property name="basename" value="messages" />
</bean>
```

Your properties file should be like below.

```
messages.properties
messages_en_US.properties
messages_zh_CN.properties
```

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32991309/spring-localechangeinterceptor-not-working) post.

Comment: its still not working, the other doubt is, If my bean declaration for `messageSource` is faulty?

Comment: Updated my answer with MessageSource bean configuration. Please check.

Comment: here `basename` should be `basenames` because there are multiple `properties` files and its not working

Comment: No, you will have to use basename and Spring will select appropriate property file as per locale. Check your property file name. "message" vs "messages". I added some sample property file name in my answer above.

Comment: I was placing `../abc_en.properties` instead of `../abc` and was confusing spring